# 700 ipads - ad hoc distribution

Tags: ipad, licensing, certificate, device, adhoc

I am developing an app for a company interested on having this app installed in 700 Ipads.
Unfortunately this company is not based in the USA and so using app store and B2B is not an option.
Is there a way for buying 4 enterprise licences, for e.g.? If so, does anyone know how to manage all those certificates in xcode?

Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming itself. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/369450) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will not let you just go out and buy several Enterprise Licenses.  The approval process requires a fair amount of paperwork to prove that you are a legitimate company for even a single license.

If all of the iPads are owned by one company you could just set them up with their own enterprise license and that should be all you need.  It would cover all 700.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this case, I assume that my client should buy the enterprise license and add me as a developer. Is that correct? How can the owner of the license prove that all the devices belong to him?

Comment: +1. Thanks for the answer Dancreek.... if u dont mind, can you please throw some more light on the process of getting a licence from a company point of view and the changes to be made from a developer point of view...

Comment: Yeah, the client needs to buy the license and add you as a developer.  I'm not sure how or even if Apple verifies that you are indeed following the rules.  ***This is pure speculation*** but I suspect that they aren't going to give you a hard time unless they are given some reason to suspect that you are blatantly abusing the Enterprise license agreement.  If your client starts just sending this app out everywhere then I would be very concerned.

Comment: A for Alpha.  From a developer's stand point there is no real difference between normal development and developing for an enterprise.  The only thing is that you don't have to send your app through Apple.  So you have more freedom.  As for the company getting licensed, they need to be prepared for a lengthy approval process.  They need a Duns & Bradstreet number and they need paperwork proving that they are actually the company that they say they are.  Apple will give you a list of documents that they consider acceptable.